# TextEdit won't open text files

Tags: textedit

Problem almost an exact opposite of [Textedit opens every Textedit file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426689/textedit-opens-every-textedit-file)

Starting today—has never happened before—neither `open -e (file)` in zsh nor File→Open… in TextEdit will open any text files!

No ACLs or extended attributes on the files tried.  Will not even open an empty file that I created with `touch` nor a file created by perl.  I **can** open them with BBEdit, and can read/display them with `more`/`cat`/`head`/`wc`/`od`.

I accepted security update macOS 13.3.1 (22E772610a) early yesterday morning, but I think (not certain) I used TextEdit yesterday without this problem.

Cmd-N for new file still works.

Only one of the 30+ filenames tried has [diacritics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458494/opening-file-doesnt-open-it-it-just-open-the-app-eg-for-pdf-preview-app-ope).

Update: The files I wanted to edit today were song lyrics.  In TextEdit, I did Cmd-N to open a new untitled blank file.  `more 01.txt` in Terminal to get the lyrics.  Copy/paste them into the blank file, and rename it Lyrics.txt.  Then [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) couldn’t open it either:

```
WGroleau@MBP Ven, Espíritu % eyeD3 --encoding utf8 --add-lyrics "~/Lyrics.txt::esp" 01\ Adoremos\ Juntos\ \(es\).mp3
usage: eyeD3 [-h] [--version] [--about] [-l LEVEL[:LOGGER]] [--profile] [--pdb] [-r]
[snip remainder of usage]
eyeD3: error: argument --add-lyrics: Unable to read file
```

Comment: Are you saying it won’t open *any* text file?  Try this (generates random text in a file):  `for (( i=1; i < 50; i++ )); do openssl rand -base64 12 >> random_text.txt; done`.  Then issue the command `open random_text.txt` or `open -a TextEdit random_text.txt`. What happens?

Comment: It's not just the security update - all ours still work - the `last reboot` command should show you all recent reboots as you narrow down or dismiss any restarts / updates as relevant

Comment: No, doesn't open that file either, but I'm not surprised.  The last reboot was the one that installed the security update.  I'll run another one to see whether it changes anything.  (After adding another detail to the question.)

Comment: Reboot fixed it.  Bug in the security update installer?  I'll assume so and report as such to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a bug in the installer for the security update.

Another reboot fixed it.

Comment: I installed the update this afternoon, but `open -e filename` still works for me without an extra reboot.

Comment: @Barmar Bugs can be specific to particular combinations of OS version, hardware, installed apps and other software, disk format, region, and/or many other factors. I'd expect a serious problem like this to affect relatively few users, else it would have been spotted before being released.

Comment: @gidds I'd expect that `open -e` is only used by few users, so a problem there might not be noticed. OTOH, I also assume that Apple has extensive regression testing.

Comment: Note that File→Open also wouldn't work.  And I guess I should add the detail that double-clicking in Finder didn't.  Nor `open file.txt` (without the `-e`)  Whatever—the reboot fixed it.